# Comparing the largest eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $k\in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is a positive-valued function on $[0,\alpha]$. Does the following hold for $0<a<b<\alpha$

$$\max_{f\in L^2[0,a],\,\|f\|_2=1} \int_0^a\int_0^a k(|x-y|)f(y)f(x)\,dxdy<\max_{g\in L^2[0,b],\|g\|_2=1} \int_0^b\int_0^b k(|x-y|)g(y)g(x)dxdy$$

Answer (score 1):

If you put the additional constraint on the RHS that $g=0$ on $(a,b]$ then it is the same as the LHS. Removing the constraint will not make it smaller. (This does not prove strict inequality.)