# Strict inequality for logarithmic integrals

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Let $0<a<b<1$. Does the following inequality hold:

$$\max_{f\in L^2[0,a],\,\,\|f\|_2=1}\Bigg|\int_0^a\int_0^af(x)f(y)\ln|x-y|dxdy\Bigg|$$
$$<\max_{g\in L^2[0,b],\,\,\|g\|_2=1}\Bigg|\int_0^b\int_0^bg(x)g(y)\ln|x-y|dxdy\Bigg|$$

?

Comment: Before any work on this logarithmic kernel, what can be said about the convergence of these double integrals ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The kernel, which has diagonal singularity, belongs to $L^2[0,t]$ for any positive $t$ so the integrals converge.

Comment: Doesn't my Answer to your [other Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728338/comparing-the-largest-eigenvalues/1740068#1740068) apply here?

Comment: @KeithMcClary The difficult part is to show that the inequality is strict.Your arguement to the more general case (namely my first question) merely shows the inequality: LHS $\leq$ RHS.

Comment: This is a really naive question, but would you get the strict inequality for the whole class of L2 functions with norm 1 if you showed that it holds for a subset of the class (I was thinking monotonic increasing specifically), since you are taking the maximum?  I feel like that might be possible to prove given that b is strictly greater than a.

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman Intuitively it should be. It would be very odd if for some $a<b$, the two quantities are equal. But for some reason I cannot come up with a proof.

Comment: @BigM oh yeah I guess that idea wouldn't be sufficient if the maximum of another subclass was greater and for that other subclass only non-strict inequality holds. shoot.

Comment: it's especially tricky too because even for really nice functions you can't use a Fubini trick and split into the product of two single integrals, and then export the result from some one-dimensional case, because the logarithm is a function of both coordinates. Maybe some change of variables might allow you to make the logarithm a function of only one variable, and that might simplify the problem somewhow? Sorry I'm just as stumped as you are

Comment: As an attempt, I tried to cook up a function from the maximal function of the integral to the left for the "larger" L^2 space.No go! I cannot think of a "cheap" proof.

Comment: I'm also confused about the space of functions for which this is defined, since presumably $\underset{|x-y| \to 0}{\lim} f(x)f(y)ln|x-y|$ wouldn't exist for all $L^2$ functions (I think?)

Comment: I mean since the logarithm isn't even locally integrable unless we exclude 0 from its domain of definition, so the integrals in the expression would have to be improper integrals, not just regular definite integrals (I think)

Comment: @WilliamKrinsman these integrals are singular and treat them as principal value. They certainly converge as the kernel are $L^2$ functions.

Comment: Oh OK. I'll try to think about this more, but this question is probably out of my league.

Comment: Can you prove this for real positive $f$, $g$ ? (I've been assuming you mean they are complex valued functions.)

Comment: Definitely.Actually I meant to show it for (real) positive functions